# How can delete azure search old document and add new document which is refreshed recently in indexer?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have created a azure search service and trying to import data using azure SQL data source and I have scheduled it to refresh the data. Data is getting refreshed properly in data source as I can verify it through indexer and index. However, in index it's getting added every time with initial document but I want only newly/updated documents in index for example if initial no. of document in index was 150 then after refresh it's increases to 156 but I want only 6 document their after refresh.

I tried both option high watermark and soft delete.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? Do you mean there are 156 rows in the SQL table and you want to have 6 documents in the index?

Comment: Can you explain how you setup soft delete so we can “look over your shoulder” and check your work? How are the 150 “expired” rows identified in your SQL table?

Comment: Actually I have one table(item) which have itemid, item, count and timestamp column. It's getting refreshed everyday. There is possibility count can be increas/decrease and timestamp will be updated every day. Also, there is possibility that no. of items(records) can be increase or decrease everyday. So o want to sync my index contents with table (item) data.

Comment: Hello Guys, can you please provide me any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure Search is designed to incrementally add new documents automatically**. So you could delete documents first and then upload documents.

However, delete document you need to specify field in document, currently there's no way to delete all the documents from an index. As you suspected deleting and re-creating the index is the way to go. Also you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7190214-possibility-to-delete-all-documents-in-an-index-wi).

If you still want the feature that remove the initial document you could add an [item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to our userVoice page.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. In user voice page I added and voted few suggestions.